# Imageslider in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to add an Imageslider into a fragment with ViewPager and Picasso. Without a fragment the imageslider works perfectly and was build according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tM7rwJoK-18). But when I want to add the Java code in a fragment, I get an error which shows that the context adapter (I suppose??) canot be applied to the fragment class.

This is what I have:

Adapter:

```
public class ActueelAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    ActueelAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls){
        this.context=context;
        this.imageUrls=imageUrls;
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .into(imageView);
        container.addView(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Fragment class:

```
public class ActueelFragment extends Fragment {

    private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
            "https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png",
            "https://www.youtube.com/yts/img/yt_1200-vfl4C3T0K.png",
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actueel, null);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ActueelAdapter adapter = new ActueelAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

The error is in this line in the fragment class: `(this, imageUrls);`.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Is it even possible to add an Imageslider to a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer was close.
Instead of using `this` in a fragment, you should use `getActivity()`

Edit:
I recommend using Glider instead of Picasso.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ue getContext() instead of this in that line. Your constructor requires Context not fragment instance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the correct context while instantiating the Adapter Object. Since your fragment resides inside the Activity,the context would be that particular Activity.
Simply use getActivity() as a context. If fragment are hosted inside FragmentActivity you need to use getContext(). 
    so simply use.

```
ActueelAdapter adapter = new ActueelAdapter(getActivity(), imageUrls);
```